# Get the file postion of each file into a stream

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, stream

I am sending multiples files from my web api but I want to read each part of the stream to convert him into a byte array , then at the end I have a list of byte[], and I can save each files:

```
 [Route("GetFiles")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFile([FromUri] List<string> filesNames)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        if (filesNames.Count == 0)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        var content = new MultipartContent();

        filesNames.ForEach(delegate (string fileName)
        {
            string filePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + fileName);
            byte[] pdf = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(pdf));
            response.Headers.Add(fileName, fileName);
        });

        var files = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);

        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, content);

        return response;
    }
```

Here is how I get one file into a stream, then convert him into a byte array to report the process percentage :

```
public static async Task<byte[]> CreateDownloadTaskForFile(string urlToDownload, IProgress<DownloadBytesProgress> progessReporter)
    {
        int receivedBytes = 0;
        int totalBytes = 0;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        using (var stream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(urlToDownload))
        {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            totalBytes = Int32.Parse(client.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.ContentLength]);
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                for (; ; )
                {
                    int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        await Task.Yield();
                        break;
                    }

                    receivedBytes += bytesRead;
                    if (progessReporter != null)
                    {
                        DownloadBytesProgress args = new DownloadBytesProgress(urlToDownload, receivedBytes, totalBytes);
                        progessReporter.Report(args);
                    }
                }
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I get the position of a stream for each files send ?

***Update*** :

I made a HttpResponseMessage like this :

```
[Route("GetFiles")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFiles([FromUri] List<string> filesNames)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        if (filesNames.Count == 0)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        filesNames.ForEach(delegate (string fileName)
        {
            string filePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + fileName);
            byte[] pdf = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(pdf), fileName);
        });

        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, content);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

        return response;
    }
```

But from my device side : When I am trying to run the request But there is nothing on the response content :

```
using (var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(urlToDownload + filesNamesArg))
            {
                var streamProvider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();

                streamProvider = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result;
            }
```

Could you show me some docs or advice ?

Comment: You should read the response as multipart-formdata, not as a full binary response. Otherwise, you will have to parse each and every part yourself using the boundary information, which I don't recommend.

Comment: Ok, ty I will try get each files then read as stream each of them in a multipart form data

Comment: @OguzOzgul Could you check the Update ? Pls

Comment: Ok. I see it. I will try to post an answer tonight, but the code (both server and client) can change, if it is ok with you. I can't find any methods to parse and process downloaded multi-part form data. Almost all articles are on how to upload. Regards.

Comment: Yea I didn't found any docs on internet showing how to send multiples files in a http response. I will try to just compress and send my files in a .zip file. Otherwise if you can provide a code to show how can we add multiples in a response It can be great. Ty for your help

Comment: What I will do is to stream all the Files in the Binary response and parse the octet stream on the client. You can also do the zip and just send it back but I don’t think it necessary unless there are other clients calling your API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What?

This answer provides a 100% working example for:

1. Serving multiple files as a single response from a web API using `multipart/mixed` content type,
2. Reading the file contents on the client by parsing the response of the web API implemented in 1

I hope this helps.

---

### Server:

The server application is a .Net 4.7.2 MVC project with web API support.

The following method is implemented in an `ApiController` and returns all the files under the `~/Uploads` folder in a single response.

Please make note of the use of `Request.RegisterForDispose` extension to register the `FileStream`s for later disposal.

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetFiles()
    {
        string filesPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Uploads");

        List<string> fileNames = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(filesPath));

        var content = new MultipartContent();

        fileNames.ForEach(delegate(string fileName)
        {
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(fileName));
            Request.RegisterForDispose(fileContent);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");
            content.Add(fileContent);
        });

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = content;
        return response;
    }
```

The response's `Content-Type` header shows as `Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="7aeff3b4-2e97-41b2-b06f-29a8c23a7aa7"` and each file is packed in different blocks separated by the `boundary`.

### Client:

The client application is a .Net Core 3.0.1 console application.

Please note the synchronous usage of the async methods. This can be easily changed to asynchronous using `await`, but implemented like this for simplicity:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:60604/api/GetImage/GetFiles").Result)
                {
                    var content = (HttpContent)new StreamContent(httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
                    content.Headers.ContentType = httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType;
                    MultipartMemoryStreamProvider multipartResponse = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
                    content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(multipartResponse);
                    for(int i = 0; i< multipartResponse.Contents.Count;i++)
                    {
                        Stream contentStream = multipartResponse.Contents[i].ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                        Console.WriteLine("Content {0}, length {1}", i, contentStream.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice ! Well explained, Ty for your time :D